# Save python plot in its original format

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have applied following codes to make a plot in python using 'IDLE editor'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
X = [0, 2, 4, 6]
Y= [0, 200, 400, 600]

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

On running the codes,following graphical window is shown:

[image]

This window gives option to "maximize", "drag" and other options as shown in red box.

Can I save this plot in this format itself.

Matplotlibrary gives option to save graphs in jpg/png formats.

But that does not retain the options to maximize and drag!

Comment: this is not format. this is application. you can not save the application functionality

Comment: Thanks a lot @LiorCohen for your valuable feedback.